# Que programas utilizar para crear apps?

Tags: app

Buenos días, soy nuevo en esto y quisiera consejos sobre que necesito para poder comenzar con la creación de app. Sea para android o iOS.

Les quedo agradecido.

Comment: Para Android tienes el IDE Android Studio. En el caso de iOS creo que utilizan el Xcode. Ya desde ahí deberías tener cierto conocimiento en los lenguajes respectivos a cada rama. Además hay un montón de tutoriales en internet de 'Como crear tu primera App'

Comment: Hola jvalverb, te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas y que tengan una mejor recepción en la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizo Xamarin desde el visual studio tanto en Mac como en windows, es una opción de visual que ya viene incluida yo te recomiendo que actualices a visual 2017. 
Para IOS te va a pedir que tengas un mac para poder compilar los programa si no tienes uno físico con una maquina virtual y ponerla en la misma red te valdría.

Suerte hay muchos tutoriales por al red yo te recomiendo el block de

https://javiersuarezruiz.wordpress.com.

Saludos.
Suerte es un mundo nuevo del que se aprende mucho.

Comment: Hola Maria, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general, y lee [answer]. Tu respuesta es perfecta para la pregunta, pero la pregunta en sí no se ajusta bien al formato del sitio (es subjetiva y  basada en opiniones), y habría que intentar no responder a ese tipo de publicaciones.